# JavaScript spread syntax in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, spread-syntax

Is there any implementation in C# like [JavaScript's spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)?

```cs
var arr = new []{"Hello", "World"};
Console.WriteLine(...arr);
```

#### 3rd party edit

Using a method

```cs
public void greet(string salutation, string recipient)
{
    Console.WriteLine(salutation + " " + recipient);    
}

// instead of this
greet(arr[0], arr[1]);
// the spread syntax in javascript allows this
greet(...arr);
```

Comment: nope....  doesn't make much sense for C#

Comment: Passing an array to `params` is as close as you're going to get.

Comment: Method with keyword `params` in parameter will be more much likely an answer. Thanks @Rob

Comment: @KeithNicholas i think it does make sense in other contexts eg `ctx.users.Select(u => new { u.id, u.otherfields } ).ToList().ConvertAll(u => new { ...u, someList.FirstOrDefault(l => l.userid == u.id).something})`

Comment: @matthewdaniel that's a little different, since in C#, unlike js, properties aren't part of an assocative array, you can't spread them onto something else....  you are kind of talking about a property spreader,  but given the limited scope of that type `new { u, someList.FirstOrDefault(l => l.userid == u.id).something}` is what you are trying to improve on

Comment: Small nitpick, `...` syntax is _not_ an operator. In the specification, it is referred to in the language grammar as [`SpreadElement`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-initializer), though informally called the "spread syntax" since it is not a context-free grammar.

Comment: Ok, As the time it was asked, the specification is not yet available. Although I will update it to refer it as a spread syntax. Thanks.

Comment: `(a, b, ...others) = getTwoParamsAndOthersIntoArray()` - not sure why this syntax wouldn't make less sense in C# than JS now it has dynamics, value tuples and deconstruction :)

Answer (score 30):

C# 12 has added the spread feature.

```
int[] row0 = [1, 2, 3];
int[] row1 = [4, 5, 6];
int[] row2 = [7, 8, 9];
int[] single = [..row0, ..row1, ..row2];
foreach (var element in single)
{
    Console.Write($"{element}, ");
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12

### Old answer (pre C# 12)

There isn't a spread option, but some useful alternatives.

1. Method Parameters aren't an array in C# unless you use the params keyword
2. Method Parameters that use the param keyword would have to either:

   1. Share the same type
   2. Have a castable shared type such as double for numerics
   3. Be of type object[] (as object is the root type of everything)

However, having said that, you can get similar functionality with various language features.

Answering your example:

**C#**

```
var arr = new []{
   "1",
   "2"//...
};

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", arr));
```

The link you provide has this example:

**Javascript Spread**

```
function sum(x, y, z) {
  return x + y + z;
}

const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(sum(...numbers));
// expected output: 6

console.log(sum.apply(null, numbers));
```

**Params**
In C#, with same type

```
public int Sum(params int[] values)
{
     return values.Sum(); // Using linq here shows part of why this doesn't make sense.
}

var numbers = new int[] {1,2,3};

Console.WriteLine(Sum(numbers));
```

In C#, with different numeric types, using double

```
public int Sum(params double[] values)
{
     return values.Sum(); // Using linq here shows part of why this doesn't make sense.
}

var numbers = new double[] {1.5, 2.0, 3.0}; // Double usually doesn't have precision issues with small whole numbers

Console.WriteLine(Sum(numbers));
```

**Reflection**
In C#, with different numeric types, using object and reflection, this is probably the closest to what you are asking for.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ReflectionExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var paramSet = new object[] { 1, 2.0, 3L };
            var mi = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Sum", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
            Console.WriteLine(mi.Invoke(null, paramSet));
        }

        public static int Sum(int x, double y, long z)
        {
            return x + (int)y + (int)z;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example with reflection is actually a lot more akin to JavaScript's [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), which was a great pre-ES6 feature that was used a lot before the spread syntax was available, but great suggestion regardless (although I wouldn't recommend it in performance-critical production code).

Comment: The double sample needs an [explicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#explicit-conversions) to int `return (int) values.Sum();`. The sum of the input  `var numbers = new double[] {1.5, 2.0, 3.0};`  is 6 since the sum 6,5 is not of type int. `When you convert a double or float value to an integral type, this value is rounded towards zero to the nearest integral value.`

Comment: c# 12 has a spread operator.

Comment: Thanks! C# team adds cool new features with each release.

Answer (score 9):

C# 12 has introduced the spread operator similar to Javascript. It is available with .Net 8

We can write

```
int[] row0 = [1, 2, 3];
int[] row1 = [4, 5, 6];
int[] row2 = [7, 8, 9];
int[] single = [..row0, ..row1, ..row2];
```

Comment: .. (<- look a spread operator ;) ) and normally today, 11/14/2023, is the release date of .NET 8.

Comment: @Timmos Hurray :D 
Which means I should update the answer ;)

Comment: It has indeed launched and is installed together with (update to) Visual Studio 17.8.

Answer (score 7):

One trick to get a behavior similar to this (without reflection) is to accept `params SomeObject[][]` and to also define an implicit operator from `SomeObject` to `SomeObject[]`. Now you can pass a mixture of arrays of `SomeObject` and individual `SomeObject` elements.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Text { get; }

    public Item (string text)
    {
        this.Text = text;
    }

    public static implicit operator Item[] (Item one) => new[] { one };
}

public class Print
{
    // Accept a params of arrays of items (but also single items because of implicit cast)

    public static void WriteLine(params Item[][] items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", items.SelectMany(x => x)));
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public void Main()
    {
        var array = new[] { new Item("a1"), new Item("a2"), new Item("a3") };
        Print.WriteLine(new Item("one"), /* ... */ array, new Item("two")); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

there is no direct pre-built library in C# to handle what is built into Spread

In order to get that functionality in C#, you need to Reflect the object and get the methods, properties, or fields by their access modifiers.

You'd do something like:

```
var tempMethods = typeof(myClass).GetMethods();
var tempFields = typeof(myClass).GetFields();
var tempProperties = typeof(myClass).GetProperties();
```

then iterate through and throw them into your dynamic object:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace myApp
{
    public class myClass
    {
        public string myProp { get; set; }
        public string myField;
        public string myFunction()
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fields = typeof(myClass).GetFields();
            dynamic EO = new ExpandoObject();
            foreach (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
            {
                AddProperty(EO, "Language", "lang" + i);
                Console.Write(EO.Language);
            }
        }

        public static void AddProperty(ExpandoObject expando, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
        {
            // ExpandoObject supports IDictionary so we can extend it like this
            var expandoDict = expando as IDictionary<string, object>;
            if (expandoDict.ContainsKey(propertyName))
                expandoDict[propertyName] = propertyValue;
            else
                expandoDict.Add(propertyName, propertyValue);
        }
    }
}
```

https://www.oreilly.com/learning/building-c-objects-dynamically

Answer (score -1):

I came here looking for the [c# range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#range-operator-) as in `numbers[ 1 .. 4]`

```cs
int[] numbers = new[] { 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
int start = 1, amountToTake = 3;
int[] subset = numbers[start..(start + amountToTake)];  // contains 10, 20, 30
numbers[1 .. 4] // returns 10, 20, 30
```

In [linqpad](/questions/tagged/linqpad) this looks like this

[image: Linqpad range operator]

Answer (score -6):

you can also do the following

```
    var a  = new List<int>(new int[]{1,2,3}){5};
    Console.WriteLine(a.Count);
```

will print 4

if you want to achieve initialization of lists or arrays with both an accompanying enumerable and parameters