# C# js-like spread (or triple dot) operator

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, reflection, expandoobject

I need to copy all properties of an object into anonymous object. In JavaScript I'd do it the following way:

```
items.map(item => ({...item, extra = 'additional property'}))
```

In C# I would have to copy property by property:

```
items.Select(item => new { item.Prop1, item.Prop2, Extra = "additional property" })
```

Or alternatively I'd use reflection and `ExpandoObject`. Any other thoughts?

Comment: In my knowledge, nothing built in like that c# for now. Please look into this as well.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886700/javascript-spread-syntax-in-c-sharp

Comment: C# 9's prospective records and `with` expressions may interest you: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#with-expressions